# Is there a whereLike function across multiple columns in knex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, knex.js

I have a table

| EmployeeNickname | EmployeeRealname | EmployeeInfo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JJ | Johnny Boy | likes bananas |
| VaejjaM | Catherine Vanejja Myerrs | Keyboard master |
| Evejjn | Jjressa Eve | employee of the month |
| Abby | Jjabby Koi | best cook |

and the following code

```
knex("TABLE1").select("EmployeeNickname", "EmployeeRealname", "EmployeeInfo").whereLike("EmployeeNickname", `${query}%`).limit(20).offset(`${page}`).orderBy("EmployeeNickname")
```

This works great for querying with the start of EmployeeNickname but I want a single query to query across multiple columns without duplicate rows:

- EmployeeNickname% (sorted AtoZ)
- EmployeeRealname% (sorted AtoZ)
- %EmployeeNickname% (sorted AtoZ)

My ideal code would be able to, when queried with "J", return in the following order

1. JJ Johnny Boy likes bananas
2. Abby Jjabby Koi best cook
3. Evejjn Jjressa Eve employee of the month
4. VaejjaM Catherine Vanejja Myerrs Keyboard master

At first I tried concatening the whereLike behind like this:

```
knex("TABLE1")
  .select("EmployeeNickname", "EmployeeRealname", "EmployeeInfo")
  .whereLike("EmployeeNickname", `${query}%`)
  .whereLike("EmployeeRealname", `${query}%`)
  .whereLike("EmployeeNickname", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderBy("EmployeeNickname")
```

but it seems to do subsequent whereLikes based on the results of the previous whereLike, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you printed the query build by Knex you'd see that you've created a number of `AND` clauses. You want `OR`.

Use `.orWhereLike()` instead of `.whereLike()`:

```
knex("TABLE1")
  .select("EmployeeNickname", "EmployeeRealname", "EmployeeInfo")
  .whereLike("EmployeeNickname", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("EmployeeRealname", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("EmployeeNickname", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderBy("EmployeeNickname")
```

[documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#wherelike)

Comment: When I execute that, it seems to reorder the result of all the 3 whereLikes together as a group.

Comment: Is it possible to list the results of the first whereLike sorted AtoZ, followed by the results of the second whereLike sorted AtoZ, followed by the results of the third whereLike sorted AtoZ, but still return the results as a group, without duplicate rows?
E.g. in the following order
1. EmployeeNickname% (sorted AtoZ)
2. EmployeeRealname% (sorted AtoZ) (omit rows already satisfied by first whereLike)
3. %EmployeeNickname% (sorted AtoZ) (omit rows already satisfied by first and second whereLike)

Comment: That is a completely distinct question. I would suggest trying to write that query in pure SQL first before going into Knex.